# Why is paper sometimes yellow?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, applied-chemistry

Where I'm from, most paper you find/get at stores has this yellowish tinge. Why is it yellow and not white?

In my chemistry book it's mentioned that paper manufacturers "refine" paper from wood pulp, and that this involves treating the pulp with $\ce{CaCO3, TiO3}$, etc and this is what makes paper white.

But the paper that's commonly available here is *yellow*(ish). Is it because the manufacturers don't carry out the required treatment with $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{TiO3}$ (why would they do that anyway?), or could it be due to some other reason?

Also, if treatment with $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{TiO3}$ is what's used to color paper white, can someone tell me *how* the color change to white (from what would've otherwise been yellow paper), actually works?

---

My question is different from the proposed duplicate. In my question, I'd like to know *why* (relatively fresh) paper is yellow, straight out of the press. I'm not asking for why paper yellows over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does paper turn yellow over time?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60647/why-does-paper-turn-yellow-over-time)

Comment: @Mithoron  read the question carefully i did not ask why it becomes yellow over time i asked that produced paper itself is yellow from the very beginning of making

Comment: Paper *is* brownish-grey. You only make it white by bleaching or mixing it with various white inorganic powders.

Comment: @Karl now i understand , from the origin its yellowish colour then we use different .... to make it white . Thanks

Comment: Do you know the name of those inorganic powder ?

Comment: You already named them. ?!?

Comment: @Karl He probably wants confirmation ;-)

Comment: @Mith Think I'll have to agree with the OP here. That doesn't look like a dupe O:)

Comment: The one who edited my post really he expressed what is in my heart ... Thanks

Comment: @Karl If those powder are used then still why yellow paper come out ...

Comment: I see. Well, you're welcome for the edit (I was hoping I didn't deviate too much from what you originally said) O:)

Comment: You use titania IF you want white paper. The *Umkehrschluss* is 100% valid.